# Paypal Express API credentials

Tags: payment-processor, paypal

I am using drupal 7.56 + civicrm 4.7.25
I have a Paypal account and I configured a Payment Processor for test with the REST API credentials from https://developer.paypal.com

REST API Sandbox account becomes PP User name
REST API Secret becomes PP Password
REST API Client ID becomes PP Signature

This configuration does not work with error message :
Payment approval failed with message :Security error Security header is not valid

Where can I find API credentials required by Payment Processor configuration ?
And more generally could someone tell a detailed end to end Paypal Express Checkout Civicrm integration ?

Comment: Try using the "test mode" payment settings and method, see if that helps? Some CiviCRM payment processors *require* you to use "test mode" to access development environment (eg PayPal Sandbox vs PayPal Live), but behaviour varies between some CiviCRM payment processors. The CiviCRM Paypal docs are [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/paypal-standard/).

Comment: Possibly answered over in https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/fixing-paypal-error-payment-processor-error-message-10002-security-error-secu?rq=1 ?